# PHP Prepared Statement SQL with where value

Tags: php, sql, mariadb, prepared-statement

I am trying to run this query on an existing row in sql table:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO 4rounds (player2_name, player2_army1_name, player2_army2_name, player2_army3_name, player2_army4_name, player2_identifier, player2_stage, player2_army1_position, player2_army2_position, player2_army3_position, player2_army4_position) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE pairing_id = ?")) {
```

but it returns the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pairing_id = ?' at line 1
```

The query works without the WHERE clause. I think there is a problem with binding the parameter in this matter and I should use VALUE as well to bind it later but I can't seem to find anything online about binding a param in this manner.

These are the binds I am trying with:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssssssss", $player2_name, $player2_army1_name, $player2_army2_name, $player2_army3_name, $player2_army4_name, $player2_identifier, $player2_stage, $player2_army1_position, $player2_army2_position, $player2_army3_position, $player2_army4_position, $pairing_id);
```

Comment: INSERT statements don't have WHERE clauses - you may want to look at UPDATE instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT` statements don't have `WHERE` clauses, and I'm not sure why you would want such a thing... Those only exist in `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries, typically.